# Can two almost identical apps be uploaded on Apple Store?

Tags: apple-store

I want to upload two apps just with color and name difference on Apple Store.

Is it possible, as I have heard that Apple blocks similar apps?

Answer (score 2):

Similar apps can be uploaded if your app has (version based app) free, paid or in-app-purchase with clear description of each version of app will minimise the chances of rejection of the app.

Else the app can be rejected by Apple under:

> 2.20 Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar Apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

[App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)